# LINQ Query over another LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to Query over another LINQ query?

I have a BindingSource object that contain the result of a LINQ expression. and that BindingSource is the DataSource of a DataGridView.

Now I would like to filter futher more the result of the BindingSource.

Is there a way to convert that BindingSource DataSource to soemthing I could query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely.  You probably will just need to cast the DataSource to an IEnumerable or IQueryable, something like this:

```
var queryable = (IEnumerable<MyObject>)myBindingSource.DataSource;
var myResults = queryable.Where(mObj => myObj.Color == "Red");
```

Comment: Interesting!! And what if I don't know the actual type of object that contain the DataSource?

Comment: Then you really can't do much in the way of querying against it.  What type of query were you expecting to execute on an entirely unknown type (not saying it's not possible, it's just rather limiting).

Comment: In fact it could be many thing, this is part a the Custom DataGridView that is use everywhere in the application, so I would  like to build something generic.

Comment: @Hugo: You don't really need to know the type of the object if you have the objects you care about implement a common interface.  So if your objects implemented an interface defined as `interface INameable { string Name; int Id;}`, then you could cast your DataSource to IEnumerable<INameable> and you'd be able to query those columns.  Short of that, you're stuck with using yuckiness like reflection and dynamic types, which isn't where we want to go...

Comment: @DaveMarkle: Thanks for your input, I'll consider this. I'm use to work with DataTable witch are more friendly to work with. By building generic method and do it all procedure. I need to change my approach I guess.

Comment: For the record... I've found a simple way to search/filter for a value in a DataGridView, whatever DataSource may be, I loop thought all rows and fields from the grid and set Rows[Index].Visible=False for field value that don't fit, and set is back Visible = True, to restore original state. It is simple but may not be very speedy for BIG DataGridView with many rows.